# cannot load calendar when publishing, works in local environment

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, fullcalendar, http-status-code-404

Trying to publish the calendar in a live environment but does not work. Works fine in a local environment.

tried using jquery cdn but does not work. changed the method return type in the controller but did not work.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var events = [];
        var selectedEvent = null;
        FetchEventAndRenderCalendar();
        function FetchEventAndRenderCalendar() {
            events = [];
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/home/GetEvents",
                success: function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, v) {
                        events.push({
                            ID: v.ID,
                            title: v.Name,
                            description: v.Description,
                            start: moment(v.Start),
                            end: v.End != null ? moment(v.End) : null,
                            color: v.ThemeColor,
                            allDay: v.IsFullDay
                        });
                    })

                    GenerateCalender(events);
                },
                error: function (error) {
                    alert('failed');
                }
            })
        }
```

jquery-1.10.2.min.js:23 GET http://www.onebase.com/home/GetEvents 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is that url valid?  Because I'm getting a `301` redirect when I try to hit it

Comment: It only works if you are in our network. its an internal url @Taplar

Comment: Then I'm not sure how this is a jquery related question.  It appears to be a server side issue

Comment: @taplar yea it’s a server side issue. Works fine in local environment.

Comment: In that case you need to rephrase your question to be about why the endpoint is not working server side and provide information about how you are trying to expose/provide that endpoint.  None of that has anything to do with the information you have currently given in the question.

Comment: I don’t know why endpoint is not working on server side and don’t know how to provide endpoint @Tapar

Comment: That's why you need to ask a question about it.  Because the information you have provided, is not you're real problem.  The endpoint not working **is**

Comment: What’s an endpoint? @Taplar

Comment: An endpoint is any url that a server exposes to clients that is intended to return content to them, or for them to access to facilitate an action.

Comment: Taplar is correct, we have no idea why your code is returning a 404. Clearly the URL you have specified in your code is not correct, but since we can't see your server config or your server code we have no idea what the correct URL should be. Since you mention it works in your local environment then I suggest you start by looking for differences between the environments in terms of the way they are set up - folder structure, routing structure, root folders or whatever.